# Is there someway to use the old dark mode?

Tags: support, design, dark-mode

I really don't like the [new colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched?cb=1), is there a way to get back the old colors for the dark mode?

Comment: Yes, just wait for someone to finish making a userstyle

Comment: No snark intended, @KevinB, some people may be unfamiliar with locating and applying user stylesheets.  Might be helpful to spell that out in an answer.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler no problem, I just don't have the userstyle and don't want to point to users currently doing it as they may abandon their work and never finish. Best to wait for someone who's completed one to come by and share it as an answer. An answer explaining how to use userstyles without one to load to accomplish the goal would be less than useful, ;)