# Contrast problem for new font color of Stack Overflow dark mode

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode, accessibility, contrast

I don't know whether it's just me or not, but I feel the new font color of Stack Overflow Dark Mode makes my eyes hurt, because using `#8CBFF2` as font color and `#2D2E2F` as the background does not fit (for me) although [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/contrast-checker/8cbff2-2d2e2f) states that it is "Very Good". What do you think?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Related to [META Stack Exchange - New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched).

Comment: You're not the only one. It really hinders my ability to actually absorb what I'm reading

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar issue due to the high contrast.

Comment: My brain makes the blue text background dimly glow blue, like a fuzzy dim version of inline code format. Much better in hi-contrast mode though.

Comment: I'm proud that I'm not the only one. It is highlighted as `Hot Meta Posts`: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426889/12715723

Comment: I don't like it, but I'm not sure if it's something I'll get used to or not.  On SE sites that don't support dark mode themselves, the new color scheme is absolute garbage with the browser extension I use, https://darkreader.org/.  With its attempt at dark mode, the difference between vote-total color and the background is *barely* perceptible, and the vote arrows barely change when clicking.  (Although I also use a separate user-script to revert the button style to a triangle, not that ugly circle, so maybe there's a bad interaction there.)

Comment: I thought that my eyes broke entirely

Comment: I am baffled someone actually has approved of this new font. Everything is high contrast now, and high contrast toggle actually does even more contrast, albeit barely discernible. I tried to get used to it, but after 5 minutes I am almost getting a headache because of it...

Comment: The fact that the code-block scrollbars were black on a very dark background when released made me think they broke something.

Comment: See [Why can't the human eye focus blue light?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30600)

Comment: Same here, it's harder to read, the difference between visited and non-visited links is not very clear, the scrollbars are very hard to see, and the salmon pink instead of red is really ugly, why change something that worked?

Comment: You're not alone, it shocked me opening the website today.

Comment: I really didn't like it when it changed, so much so that I asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426890/is-there-someway-to-use-the-old-dark-mode). But now, **after 1 day of use**, it is literally hurting my eyes! I had to switch my site to the light mode for it to be minimally usable.

Comment: Text is now a little too bright for my eyes in dark mode. @PeterCordes same issue for me with darkreader and no userscript targeting the button style.

Comment: At first I thought that something had gone wrong with my monitor, then I thought that I would get used to the new colors, but now I don't think so. The new dark mode looks terrible to me and is much harder to read than the old one. I find the red and green inbox and vote notifications to be particularly problematic.

Comment: Getting rid of the `bottom-border` and changing the tag background to something like `--theme-tag-background-color: rgb(48, 50, 51);` really, really helps. The mix of "blues" in the Top Questions entries along with the bright outlines around the elements really make the site hard to read in dark-mode.

Comment: Someone at Stack Overflow please fix this high contrast colors. Who the heck had this idea of changing perfectly fine colors. Using dark mode on editors and other sites and suddenly coming to stack overflow to be greeted with these god-forbiden colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, there is a response from `Staff`: [Update: New Colors Launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232/879181)

> ## Updated Dark Mode
>
> We have heard your feedback on the saturation of Dark mode. The original palette that was shared targeted a -70Lc, but we have lowered that to -60Lc in light of feedback. This is much closer to what was shared in round of feedback before launch. We value your feedback and hope that this strikes a better balance of hitting accessibility standards set out by the community while maintaining a pleasant experience.
> If this dark mode is still too high in contrast for our default dark mode, we will need to rethink our alignment with APCA for dark mode.

Answer (score 18):

### Dark mode accessibility problem

I have trouble reading the white on light green shown here:

[image]

And I have normal vision. [WCAG's Color Contrast Checker](https://www.siegemedia.com/contrast-ratio#%23ffffff-on-%238dceab) says the contrast ratio is only 1.81, not 4.5 or higher like it should be. I can't imagine how infuriating this would be for someone with visual impairments.

Comment: Also called out in part over here: ["Related questions" section number font color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393999)

Comment: White on light green?  Whose bright idea was that?  (Excuse the pun)  I'm not a fan of WCAG's contrast measurement but only because I consider it overly optimistic - if it says it's bad, it must be really really bad.

Comment: Also noted in the Meta "New Colors" announcement question. But yes, the new colors for dark-mode produce a lot of eye-strain and make the site hard to read. Human nature/factors draw you eyes to try and resolve text on a page. With poor contrast (poor colors), it is quite taxing.